# tsc doesn't find local module declaration, but Webstorm does

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm writing a TypeScript definition file for the [recase NPM package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/recase), and so I'm following the [DefinitelyTyped contribution guidelines](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/contributing.html), part of which is to run (in my case)

```
tsc --noImplicitAny recase/recase-tests.ts
```

This produces the error:

```
recase/recase-tests.ts(1,22): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'recase'. 'C:/dev/recase-typings/node_modules/recase/recase.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Slightly trimmed, this is my project structure:

```
.
+-- recase
|   +-- recase.d.ts
|   +-- recase-tests.ts
+-- package.js
+-- tsconfig.json
```

Apart from description, author, and similar fields, this is my `package.json` (Trying to get it to work I've put both `main` and `typings` properties in there, having none or either also does not work):

```
{
    "name": "recase-typings",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "recase": "^1.0.4"
    },
    "typings": "recase",
    "main": "recase"
}
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "recase"
    }
}
```

This is `recase/recase.d.ts`:

```js
declare module 'recase' {
    namespace recase {
        function camelCopy(orig: any): any;
        function snakeCopy(orig: any): any;
    }
}
```

And this is `recase/recase-tests.ts`:

```js
import {recase} from 'recase';

const snake = recase.snakeCopy(
    {
        FOO: 1,               // Exception
        abcXyz: {             // Normal
            _abcXyz: [          // private
                {__abcXyz: 1}   // very private
                , {___abcXyz: 1}   // very very private
            ],
        },
    },
);
const camel = recase.camelCopy(
    {
        foo: 1,                // Exception
        abc_xyz: {             // Normal
            _abc_xyz: [          // private
                {__abc_xyz: 1}   // very private
                , {___abc_xyz: 1}   // very very private
            ],
        },
    },
);
```

I am on Windows 7 and just did a remove reinstall of typescript and typings, because the previous install was crashing. I first used `yarn global remove` and `npm un -i`, then manually deleted `tsc` files and folders that remained in `/AppData/Local/Yarn/config/global/node/global/` and its `.bin/`, and in NPM's modules folder.

To reinstall I used `yarn global add typescript` and `yarn global add typings`. Using `yarn` to install TypeScript produced a line saying I "probably meant to install TypeScript" and to use `npm install typescript -g`, and since the `tsc` command `was not found` at that point, I followed it up with the recommended command.

I find it strange that WebStorm compiles the file just fine, and TSLint gives no errors, but `tsc` doesn't find the declaration file. **How can I get `tsc` to find the declaration file?**

It might be worth noting that `tsc` actually does produce a `.js` file which has the exact same contents as when I compile through WebStorm. The closest issue discussion I've been able to find is [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3808), in which case the root cause was not having declared it as an Ambient External Module, but putting `export` in front of `declare module 'recase'` makes TSLint give me "TS2668:'export' modifier cannot be applied to ambient modules and module augmentations since they are always visible" and from what I've been able to surmise from elsewhere my module declaration is already ambient.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with `recase.d.ts`

When written like this it works:

```js
export function camelCopy(orig: any): any;
export function snakeCopy(orig: any): any;
```

I had failed to comprehend that the file itself is a module.